# Why does CodePush OTA update nuke my fonts?

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-vector-icons

I've got codepush working for a staging build of an app I hope to soon have in production.

On initial download from the app store, the fonts are looking great! My version checking info that I have in the app shows me that I'm using the bundled version of the `bundle.js`

If I force-quit and re-launch the app (causing an update) the fonts are no longer found in the application. They display the "missing glyph" image (see screenshot below).

I'm hoping for either a solution, some tricks to try, or just some ideas about how to further debug and understand what is causing this. I'm a little stuck because when I try to run the app in debug mode, it just uses the latest codepush version instead of downloading a new one.

[image]